# Append % sign to this excel cell which uses a function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this cell in Excel 2013. The contents of the cell is;

```
=xlqChangePercent($D2,$AP$1)
```

This function returns `1.00` which is displayed in the cell. I want this cell to display `1.00%`. I tried  `=xlqChangePercent($D2,$AP$1)%` but the cell becomes `0.01`. How do I get the cell to display `1.00%`?

Comment: Why the negative vote? It may be stupid question to you, but not to me. Please be patient to not-so-savvy people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format the cell to percentage - either use the menu or right-click on the cell and choose format.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use `=xlqChangePercent($D2,$AP$1)%`, then format the cell as percentage. This is the answer. Please add this part to your answer. THanks.

Comment: I don't see how the % symbol helps just added to the end, but what does work is the ampersand - disadvantage is that you can no longer use the cell contents as a number : =xlqChangePercent($D2,$AP$1)&"%" , the formatting allows further calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Either append `/100` to your formula and format `%` (retains content as a number) or format the cell with a custom format of:

```
 #.00"%"
```

which results in a text string.